# Неправильная кодировка в AJAX

Tags: ajax, кодировка, php

Знаю, вопрос уже был, но решения я не нашёл, передаю перменные, в одной пермененной русский текст (rName), перегоняю её в windows-1251, вывожу на экран - всё норм. Пробую добавить в БД ошибка (Unknown column 'С‹РєСЂСѓСЂРє' in 'field list') везде кодировка windows-1251, есть ещё один скрипт - там тоже русский текст, всё норм работает. Разница только перемененные из AJAX, в том передаю

```
`data: "rKod="+rKod+"&rLogin="+rLog...`
```

а здесь

```
data: {rKod:rKod, rEmail:rEmail, rLogin:rLogin, rPass:rPass, rPass2:rPass2, rName:rName}
```

в этом скрипте почему-то первым способом не доходит одна переменная (неважно какая, но одна не доходит)

```
session_start();
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");
    if ($_SESSION['secpic'] == trim($_POST['rKod'])) {
        $rLogin = trim($_POST['rLogin']);
        $rPass  = trim($_POST['rPass']);
        $rPass2 = trim($_POST['rPass2']);
        $rEmail = trim($_POST['rEmail']);
        $rName  = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1251", $_POST['rName']);

        if ($rLogin == '') {
            die("Невірний логін<br />\n");
        } elseif (!preg_match("/^\w{3,}$/", $rLogin)) {
            die("Логін містить недопустимі символи, або їх менше трьох!<br />\n");
        }
        if ($rName == '') {
            die("Невірне Ім'я<br />\n");
        } elseif (!preg_match("/^[а-яА-Я]{3,}$/", $rName)) {
            die("Ім'я містить недопустимі символи, або їх менше трьох!<br />\n");
        }
        if ($rEmail == '') {
            die("E-mail не знайдено<br />\n");
        } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/", $rEmail)) {
            die("E-mail введено невірно<br />\n");
        }
        if ($rPass == '' || $rPass2 == '') {
            die("Пароль не введено<br />\n");
        } elseif ($rPass !== $rPass2) {
            die("Другий раз пароль введено невірно<br />\n");
        } elseif (!preg_match("/^\w{3,}$/", $rPass)) {
            die("Пароль має недопустимі символи!<br />\n");
        }

        $mdPassword = md5($rPass);
        $time       = time();
        $inc        = 1;
        include("min/1.php");
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
        mysql_query("SET character_set_client = cp1251");
        mysql_query("SET collation_connection=cp1251_general_ci");
        mysql_query("SET character_set_results = cp1251");
        echo $rName . '<br>';
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login, pass, email, timestamp, name) VALUES ('$rLogin','$mdPassword','$rEmail',$time, $rName)", $connect);

        echo mysql_error($connect) . '<br>';

        if (mysql_error($connect) != "") {
            die("Пользователь с таким логином уже существует, выберите другой<br />\n");
        }

    ...

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если данные отправлены через AJAX, то на сервер они придут в UTF-8, используйте `iconv`, чтобы привести их необходимой кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (login, pass, email, timestamp, name) VALUES ('$rLogin','$mdPassword','$rEmail',$time, $rName)", $connect);
```

какого .... тут $rName без кавычек а???